# Solving T(n,m) = 3n + T(n/3,m/3)

Tags: recurrence-relation

I have the below recurrence:
\begin{align}
T(n, 1) &= 3n \\
T(1, m) &= 3m \\
T(n, m) &= 3n + T(\tfrac{n}{3}, \tfrac{m}{3})
\end{align}

How to get a tight asymptotic bound for $T(n, n^2)$ assuming that $n$ is a power of 3?

Using the substitution method for $T(m,n)$, I get a very weird relation:

$$T(n,m) = 3n + \frac{m}{3^{k-1}} +  n\left(3 - \frac{1}{3^{k-1}}\right),$$
where $k = \log_3 n$.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to the site! What's $k$?

Comment: Your solution cannot be right. Plugging $m=1$, you don't get $3n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(N,M) = T(3^N,3^M)/3$. If $N \geq M$ then
\begin{align}
S(N,M) &= 3^N + S(N-1,M-1) \\ &= 3^N + 3^{N-1} + S(N-2,M-2) + \\ &= \cdots \\ &= 3^N + \cdots + 3^{N-M+2} + S(N-M+1,1) \\ &= 3^N + \cdots + 3^{N-M+1}.
\end{align}
Similarly, if $N \leq M$ then
\begin{align}
S(N,M) &= 3^N + S(N-1,M-1) \\ &= 3^N + 3^{N-1} + S(N-2,M-2) + \\ &= \cdots \\ &= 3^N + \cdots + 3^{N-M+2} + S(1,M-N+1) \\ &= 3^N + \cdots + 3^{N-M+2} + 3^{M-N+1}.
\end{align}
It follows that
$$
S(N,M)= \Theta(3^N + 3^{M-N}),
$$
and so
$$
T(n,m) = \Theta(n + m/n).
$$
In particular,
$$
T(n,n^2) = \Theta(n).
$$

Comment: The recurrence is really strange. It seems that T(n, n^4) = O(n^3), but T(n^2, n^4) is only O (n^2). Or T(x, y) = O (max (x, y/x)).

Comment: Indeed, $O(f + g)$ is the same as $O(\max(f,g))$.